# WPF creating a list

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a collection of strings in C# MAINWINDOW.xaml.cs like this

```
public class NameList : ObservableCollection<Shortcuts>
        {
            public NameList()     : base()
            {
                Add(new Shortcuts("ctrl", "b","s"));
                Add(new Shortcuts("ctrl", "b","m"));
                Add(new Shortcuts("ctrl", "b","p"));
                Add(new Shortcuts("ctrl", "b","1"));
            }
        }

        public class Shortcuts
        {
            private string firstkey;
            private string secondkey;
            private string lastkey;

            public Shortcuts(string first, string second, string last)
            {
                this.firstkey = first;
                this.secondkey = second;
                this.lastkey= last;
            }

            public string Firstkey
            {
                get { return firstkey; }
                set { firstkey = value; }
            }

            public string Secondkey
            {
                get { return secondkey; }
                set { secondkey = value; }
            }

            public string Lastkey
            {
                get { return lastkey; }
                set { lastkey = value; }
            }
        }
    }
```

Then in the MainWindow.xaml itself I have a combobox and I would like to bind these items to the combobox so this is what I did

```
<Window x:Class="Testing_learning.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:c="clr-namespace:Testing_learning"
        Title="Outlook Context Settings" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
         <c:ListName Key ="NameListData"/>

    </Window.Resources>
```

oh BTW the project name is ***Testing_learning*** that is why there is this

```
xmlns:c="clr-namespace:Testing_learning"
```

BUT the problem is that when i add this line of code

```
<Window.Resources>
         <c:ListName Key ="NameListData"/>

        </Window.Resources>
```

I get an error at c:ListName the type ListName was not found why is this?
Any thoughts?

Screenshot 1 
[image]

Screenshot 2
[image]

Comment: Wow that was so immature of me but the same problem even if i change it to <c:NameList Key ="NameListData"/>...more over the dropdown gives me 'App' when i press c: the options that i get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have one more typo: `Key` has to be `x:Key`

```
<Window.Resources>
    <c:NameList x:Key="NameListData" />
</Window.Resources>
```

and you have nested your classes in MainWindow class. Move it out:

```
namespace Testing_learning
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }

    public class NameList : ObservableCollection<Shortcuts>
    {
        ...
    }

    public class Shortcuts
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: still the same thing pls see the attached screenshot.

Comment: Realized it was nested..(tap myself on the head..very hard!)

Answer (score 2):

It appears to be a typo?  Your C# has NameList, but your XAML has ListName.

Comment: Wow that was so immature of me but the same problem even if i change it to <c:NameList Key ="NameListData"/>...more over the dropdown gives me 'App' when i press c: the options that i get.

Answer (score 2):

Your class definition:

```
public class NameList : ObservableCollection<Shortcuts>
    {
    //[…]
```

Your xaml:

```
<c:ListName Key ="NameListData"/>
```

`NameList` is different to `ListName`. Since you don't have a `ListName` class you'll see the "ListName was not found" error.

Comment: Wow that was so immature of me but the same problem even if i change it to <c:NameList Key ="NameListData"/>...more over the dropdown gives me 'App' when i press c: the options that i get.

Answer (score 0):

When I moved the two classes to separate files it worked.

EDIT:

Building also fixes the problem even if the classes are in MainWindow.xaml

[image]

Comment: I too thought of that but still the same thing why is that so?

Comment: I am following this tutorial over here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx

Comment: what's not working ? it works just fine for me, and adding an item template works too

Comment: Its telling me the same thing as in my first error, how come it works for you?.. can paste ur code or share your project tks